# How I could create a font that show the space " " as simbol like this "_"?

Tags: fonts, cpu-word, letter

I dont know How I could do this  I need to get an idea for create a font in format ttf

PLease help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fontforge can read and write ttf files. Just edit an existing font and change the space character.